# Passing Instance and Non-instance Variables to Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial, **_approve.html.erb** in my **views/users** directory that I would like to use in my **views/friendships/index.html.erb**

The partial works fine within my **views/users/show.html.erb** with an instance variable. However it seems to break when i call it from **views/friendships/index.html.erb**

**_approve.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Approve", friend_approval_path(@user), :class => "btn primary", :remote => false %>
```

**views/users/show.html.erb** renders fine here:

```
<%= render 'approve' %>
```

**views/friendships/index.html.erb** throws errors here:

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/approve', :locals => {:user => invite} %
```

This is the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"friendships", :action=>"approve"}
```

Comment: And *what* error(s) does it throw? (And you don't need to set remote false; that's the default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user` is an instance variable--not a local.

Either create a `@user` instance variable from your friendships controller, or pass in a local `user` from the user controller, or put logic in your partial to choose between the two.

Comment: Makes sense. I added in: 

<% user = @user%>
 <%= render :partial => 'approve', :locals => {:invite => user}%>

That feels a little janky, but it works!

Comment: @Rapture I don't understand the `{ :invite => user }` part, but okay. In any case, ew; IMO that's the worst of the three options I provided.

Comment: I guess that was the lowest hanging fruit for me, because I'm not sure how to set up the logic in the partial to handle both. And creating an @ user instance variable from my friendships controller seemed like it wouldn't be possible because it's an index and has lots of @ user listed? I would love to know how to do this more properly! It seems janky to me as well!

Comment: `<% foo = @user || user %>` seems easy enough (or something like that).

Comment: Sometimes the simple things are what get me i guess. Still learning. Appreciate the patience and help! That worked great.